# Using Erwin to create DDL for Amazon Redshift

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, erwin

Has anyone been successful in creating DDL using Erwin for Amazon Redshift? If not, does anyone know of a way to convert, say a MySQL DDL from Erwin, to an Amazon Redshift compliant DDL?

I understand that Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2. However, there are numerous PostgreSQL features that are no compatible with Redshift. So, if I use a tool to convert MySQL DDL to PostgreSQL DDL and try to execute is against Redshift, I always run into issues.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that works (with limited features) is to forward engineer erwin model into ODBC 3.x compliant schema i.e.

1. Select Target Database (Actions ---> Target Database) as ODBC/Generic with version as 3.0.

The reason this works is because ODBC/Generic sql can be executed on Redshift without any changes.

**NOTE**: Features like

1. Identity
2. Encode

may need manipulating FET template or more.

However, just selecting target database to ODBC may suffice in general.

**Update**:
this [link](http://erwin.com/news/erwin-expands-data-management-platform-with-new-version-of-industry-leading-data-modeling-solution/) suggests that newer DM may have further support for Redshift.